# add new column after another column in symfony using docrine schema

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

**Code**

Entity for room table.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Room
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

   /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $groupOrder;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"after": "active","default": false})
     */
    private $isAssociable;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default" : 1})
     */
    private $active = true;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;
}
```

I'm running following command on console, but the output is not as expected

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

**Expected Output**

> ALTER TABLE room ADD is_associable TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
>   AFTER active;

**What I'm getting(Output)**

> ALTER TABLE room ADD is_associable TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL;

Comment: Doctrine does not support this as "...Doctrine is built to be as datastore agnostic as sensibly possible. From a data perspective point-of-view, it will not matter if your new column is placed in a particular position or not,..."

Comment: @JasonStephenson any alternative to this approach except migration?

Comment: None that I know of, unless you do it manually outside of doctrine, sorry

Comment: I think I should do it via migration then :P, thanks @JasonStephenson

Comment: You have to do it manually if you it's a production database. The only other way is to order your property in your file, drop the table, update the schema

Comment: It's strange for Doctrine to call it "agnostic" to follow the order of columns as defined in the ORM YML (or whatever file you define it in) but ignore it when new columns are added in the middle. It should follow our definition, not pretend it's "agnostic".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that natively you can't do that in Doctrine. Option parameter for the column which might handle that isn't available. Anyway maybe you can achieve that by (of course all of ideas are a workarounds):

- creating custom "position" annotation for field, of course you need write custom command which will run `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` and will modify an sql output (it's just my idea).
- do that with using migration where you will put raw sql
- create PR or Issue to Doctrine ORM project on github [here](https://github.com/doctrine/orm).

Comment: I don't understand why Doctrine would follow the order of columns in the ORM YML (or whatever file) definition when creating the table initially, but ignore the order for any new columns added after that when updating the table.

Comment: @SteveExdia The whole point of Doctrine is being engine agnostic. Most vendors don't even implement custom positions for `ALTER TABLE` statements and, even in MySQL, it can be too expensive to be the default.

Answer (score 0):

Using symfony migrations is the way to go.

Doc: https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html

You can use the command `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`
Which will create a new migration file with the changes from your entities and your current database state.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question. Doctrine migration generator will just append new columns at the end of the table.

Comment: You can change the order of what the migration made you. Or are you asking for doctrine to add columns to an already created tabled and you just want for example, to be right after the auto id column and in between two other previously created columns?
Thanks

Comment: Then the solution you're proposing is to edit the generated SQL manually?

Comment: Exactly. He could also create a backup of the content of his table.
DROP and then create the new CREATE TABLE ....
And then move the insert values one column left or right, depending or where he moved the columns orders.
It takes a lot of work but can be done.